# fillWidth property in Vbox doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I wrote project for test fillwidth property as said in this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html#fillWidth), but my result is different with it.

Result
[image: this is result image]

and this is my code :

```
public class VBoxSample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Button b1 = new Button( " it's test of size ") ;
        Button b2 = new Button( " VBOX test") ;
        Button b3 = new Button( " it's test") ;

        VBox vbox = new VBox( 10 , b1 , b2 ,b3) ;
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene( vbox ));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What part I did wrong? And why `fillWidth` didn't work for button as Oracle doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBox` only resizes children to their `maxWidth`s which for `Button`s is the size computed based on the content size of the `Button` by default. ([`Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_COMPUTED_SIZE) is used as default value for the `maxWidth` property.)

If you remove those constraints you get the desired result:

```
b1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
b2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
b3.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```